# Two queries merging

Tags: mysql, merge

I need to merge two queries:

First query:

```
SELECT `p`.`name`, `posts`.*
FROM `polls` `p`, `posts` 
WHERE `p`.`id` = `posts`.`guid` 
AND `first` = {$id} 
AND `text` LIKE ?
```

with... second query:

```
SELECT SUM(`deleted` = 0) AS 'posts'
FROM `posts`
WHERE `first`
NOT IN 
(
SELECT `id` 
FROM `posts` 
WHERE `deleted` = 1 
AND `first` = `id`
) AND `first` = {$fid}
```

Is there any chance to merge them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION.  You'll have to make them return the same columns though.  The second query will have to return blank values for everything else.

Comment: Okay, could you help me with this `UNION`? Because I've tried many ways with that and query always fails.

Comment: I think `UNION` won't help in this case because `SELECT` statements have a different number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the query is trying to achieve, or what kind of results the queries produce. I think query 1 searches for posts like text, query 2 searches for deleted posts by ID. I've done a jig around, it should work if both queries generate the same amount of rows.

Changes:
1 You'd need to change the AS in the second query to a unique name (so here, posts_sum).
2 I've also removed the second ID join.

Check it out:

```
 SELECT `p`.`name`, `posts`.*, SUM(`deleted` = 0) AS 'posts_sum'
 FROM `polls` `p`, `posts` 
 WHERE `p`.`id` = `posts`.`guid` 
 AND `first` = {$id} 
 AND `text` LIKE ?
 AND `first`
 NOT IN 
 (
    SELECT `id` 
    FROM `posts` 
    WHERE `deleted` = 1 
    AND `first` = `id`
 )
```